# adaptive card's content could not be displayed in GCCH teams

Tags: botframework

I use the sample code([git code](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/javascript_nodejs/07.using-adaptive-cards/index.js)) to send adaptive card to teams gcch, after I config ChannelService as https://botframework.azure.us, a message is sent to teams successfully, but the content is not displayed, even if the adaptive card's content is only a simple 'textblock'.
Any help on this is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

[adaptive card's content could not be displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkc3J.png)

Comment: Are you able to use Adaptive Cards outside of GCC? Have you tried this scenario outside GCC?

Comment: If this issue is specific to GCC High, you'll need to contact the appropriate support channel for resolution.